# Problem in one to one functions

Tags: functions

Here is a question, the content in red is the question and the underlined area was left blank to answer it. The diagram is made by me to help understand the question,

[image]

I am unable to get the point that how does it prove that it is one to one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

______ #1: "$g$ is one to one"

______ #2: "$f$ is one to one"

The meaning of "$g$ is one to one" is that $g(x_1)=g(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2$ for any $x_1,x_2\in B$.

In your case, we have assumed that
$$(g\circ f)(a_1)=(g\circ f)(a_2).$$
In other words,
$$g(f(a_1))=g(f(a_2)).$$
Thus, we have two elements $f(a_1),f(a_2)\in B$ such that $g(f(a_1))=g(f(a_2))$. By the assumption that $g$ is one to one, this implies that $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$.

Then use the same reasoning to conclude that $a_1=a_2$ because $f$ is one to one.

Thus, $(g\circ f)(a_1)=(g\circ f)(a_2)\implies a_1=a_2$ for any $a_1,a_2\in A$. Therefore the function $(g\circ f):A\to C$ is one to one.

Comment: How did you came up with,"The meaning of "g is one to one" is that g(x1)=g(x2)⟹x1=x2 for any x1,x2∈B?" The meaning of one to one to me is that there will be different outputs for all inputs. How is x1= x2 then?

Comment: A more precise way of saying it is "there will be different outputs for different inputs". Thus, if inputs $x_1$ and $x_2$ give the **same** output (i.e. $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$), then they must be the **same** input (i.e. $x_1=x_2$).